# Explode function separator white spaces

Tags: php

```
<?php

$str = '1000 - 2000';
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);
// zero limit
print_r(explode('-',$str,0));


?>
```

http://ideone.com/rFvgZI

I am trying to get two array items '1000' and '2000' to no avail. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: remove the third argument from `explode`

Comment: Why are you using 0 limit?

Comment: Zero limit is treated as limit = 1.

Comment: also, if you're going to use regex for this, you may as well just `preg_match_all('~\d+~',$str,$nums);`

Comment: thanks crayon ! last q - how can i echo array[0] for example? btw your preg_match code doesn't work for me... ideally i would like to remove all white spaces and commas at the same time...

Comment: the if you're sticking with your original code and removing the 3rd arg of `explode`, then you'd do `echo $str[0];` and `echo $str[1];` if you go the `preg_match_all` route, then you'd do `echo $nums[0][0];` and `echo $nums[0][1];`

Comment: awesome first example works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the third parameter to explode. Setting that third parameter to 0 you essentially get a one element array returned containing the entire string...

> ```
> PARAMETERS
> · $delimiter
> - The boundary string.
>
> · $string
> - The input string.
>
> · $limit
> -  If  $limit  is  set and positive, the returned array will contain a
>    maximum of $limit elements with the last element containing the rest 
>    of $string.  If the $limit parameter is negative, all components except 
>    the last -$limit are returned.  If the $limit parameter is zero, then 
>    this is treated as 1.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
$arr = preg_split('/\s*-\s*/', $str);
```

This is splitting the given string around (zero or more white spaces(\s*) + one hyphen + zero or more white spaces(\s*)).

Comment: Can you explain a little bit your answer? This is being flagged as a low quality post.

Answer (score 0):

What about just that (for all spaces):

```
<?php
    $str = '1000 - 2000';
    $tmp = explode('-', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str));
    var_dump($tmp);
?>
```